# How to use a Postgres DataBase to develop with JHipster?

Tags: postgresql, jhipster

My problem is that I'm new in JHipster. I can construct a basic application using the H2 disk persistance method to develop and it works fine, but when I try to build a new project using the Postgres db as development method, and I configure de database attributes in the application-dev.yml file, it just doesn't work, I can't even log in.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the fragment of the application-dev.yml file where I configure the access db. Of course I've already created the database (ControlAcceso), but it's empty, I thought the tables creation will be automatic, please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ControlAcceso
    username: postgres
    password: root
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
```

Comment: The tables will be created by Liquibase on application startup. Did you generate your project using postgresql as development database? How do you start your app?

Comment: Yes sr, I actually fixed the problem, the driver of the db wasn't installed correctly, so I just reinstalled the db and it worked fine. But I have a question as weell. If you make changes on the .jdl file entities, for example adding a new atribute to a tabe or deleting one table, and having changed  de some views, what happen if I re-generate the project?

Comment: Have you seen this video about side-by-side approach ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use docker you could add testcontainers when using psql also in dvelopment to get similar experience like using h2 https://atomfrede.gitlab.io/2019/05/jhipster-with-testcontainers/